# Backup a SQL Server database with current date

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I'm trying to backup databases using the current date time to create a unique filename.

I keep getting incorrect syntax on the '+' before @TimeDate

My Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackUpDatabase]
(@DatabaseName Varchar(256))
AS
Begin
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256);
SET @TimeDate = CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 113);
BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName
TO DISK = 'C:\SQLEXPRESSBACKUP\DB'+ @TimeDate + '.bak'
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME= @DatabaseName, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10
END
```

And I am unable to figure what to search on, to know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, look at what your `@TimeDate` value generates:

```
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256);
SET @TimeDate = CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 113);
SELECT @TimeDate
```

**Produces:**

```
26 Sep 2017 11:49:07:650
```

This wouldn't be an acceptable file name when appended to your string. So you need to cleanse this to remove `:` characters.

```
SET @TimeDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 126), ':','');
```

Secondly, it doesn't like you concatenating a string here so use a variable instead that you can prepare before:

```
TO DISK = 'C:\SQLEXPRESSBACKUP\DB'+ @TimeDate + '.bak'
```

Change to:

```
DECLARE @location VARCHAR(100) = 'C:\SQLEXPRESSBACKUP\DB' + @timedate + '.bak'
```

**Full soution:**

```
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256);
SET @TimeDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 126), ':','');
DECLARE @location VARCHAR(100) = 'C:\SQLEXPRESSBACKUP\DB' + @timedate + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName
TO DISK = @location
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME= @DatabaseName, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10
```

Comment: yes i found that out, really good answer ! So all i needed really was to make a @location variable to save it in ?

Comment: yes, the location can be built up before you call the backup command, and it will be happy.

Comment: also, pay attention to the `REPLACE` used to remove the `:` characters from the timedate.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable `@ExecuteQuery` and then assign this variable value to `TO DISK`.

Like this.

```
DECLARE @ExecuteQuery Varchar(1000);
SET @ExecuteQuery  = 'C:\SQLEXPRESSBACKUP\DB' +  CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 113) + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName
TO DISK = @ExecuteQuery 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME= @DatabaseName, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10
```

Comment: @andrelange91 did this code actually work with the `:` characters generated by `GETDATE()`, it didn't when I tested it, that's why I replaced them in my solution.

Comment: no it didn't work with the :, but all other worked. I didn't even realise it before now, that was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Dynamic SQL to build the query rather than trying to add in the variables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackUpDatabase](@DatabaseName VARCHAR(256))
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @TimeDate VARCHAR(256);
         SET @TimeDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), GETDATE(), 113);
         DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
         SET @sql = '
BACKUP DATABASE ['+@DatabaseName+']
TO DISK = ''C:\SQLEXPRESSBACKUP\DB'+@TimeDate+'.bak''
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME= '''+@DatabaseName+''', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10';
         PRINT @sql;
--exec (@sql)
     END;
```

The `PRINT @SQL` will show you what is going to be run, if you are happy with it then remove that and uncomment out `exec (@sql)`

Comment: I am getting this error, when i try exec the procedure, : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @andrelange91 my bad- added an extra quote in by accident, altered it